# Laravel - After user registers, log them in

Tags: php, laravel

I have a simple register submit class:

```
public function registerSubmit(Request $request){
   $this->validate($request,[
       'name'=>'string|required|min:2',
       'email'=>'string|required|unique:users,email',
       'password'=>'required|min:8|confirmed',
   ]);
   $data=$request->all();
   $check=$this->create($data);        
   Session::put('user', $data['email']);
   return redirect('/');
```

It registers the user just fine but after I redirect to the home page, it didn't log them in. They then have to go to the login page, type in the same credentials and then they are logged in. Kind of a lame 2 step process.

```
public function loginSubmit(Request $request){

    $data= $request->all();
        if(Auth::attempt(['email' => $data['email'], 'password' => $data['password'], 'status'=>'active'])){
    Session::put('user', $data['email']);
    return redirect('/');
```

Anyway to just have the register user automatically login? Based on the code it should start the session but it doesn't. I am using file session in the congif also.

Comment: why you are not using Laravel default Auth so it can do all for you?

Comment: i might migrate to that. (I should) This is a Github project that I have forked that has its own auth controller

Answer (score 0):

You can use a middleware like this:

```
Route::get('/login',[YOURCONTROLLER::class,'login'])->middleware('alreadyLoggedIn');
```

and this can be your middleware

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AlreadyLoggedIn
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse)  $next
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Session()->has('loginId') && (url('login')==$request->url()|| url('registration')
        ==$request->url())){
            return back();
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

dont forget to add it in Karnel.php

```
 protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'alreadyLoggedIn' => \App\Http\Middleware\AlreadyLoggedIn::class,
     ,
    ];
}
```

also I write a simple controller here for you:

```
public function registration(){

        return view("auth.registration");
    }

    public function  registerUser(Request $request){

        $request->validate([
            'name'=>'required',
            'email'=>'required|email|unique:users',
            'password'=>'required|min:3|max:10'
        ]);
        $user = new User();
        $user->name=$request->name;
        $user->email=$request->email;
        $user->password=Hash::make($request->password);
        $res=$user->save();
        if($res){
            return back()->with('success','You have registerd successfuly');
            }else{
            return back()->with('fail','fail');
        }

    }
```